# Application of maximum principle to a function of a complex variable.

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

The question is: $f:U \to \mathbb{C}$ analytic and non constant on $U$ (open and connected). Show that $|\Re(f)|$, $|\Im(f)|$ and $\Re(f)^4 + \Im(f)^4$ do not attain local maxima.

I've attempted to show this for $|\Re(f)|$ and $|\Im(f)|$ (for $f$ valued at $z \in \mathbb{C}$) via the following method:

Assume $|\Re(f)|$ attains a local maxima on $U$, then $\exists$ $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ such that  $|\Re(f)|$ is a local maximum.

$\frac {\partial}{\partial z}|\Re(f)| = \frac {\Re(f)}{|\Re(f)|} = 0 \Rightarrow \Re(f) = 0$

So, since $f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ for $z=x+iy$ for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, then $u(x,y) = 0$  and also by $f$ being analytic we know that Cauchy-Riemann must hold $\Rightarrow v(x,y) = 0$ this suggests that $f(z) = 0 \Rightarrow$ f is constant, which is a contradiction. Thus $|\Re(f)|$ attains no local maxima (same for $|\Im(f)|$)

Would this be an acceptable way of proving this?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, your calculation is wrong: the absolute value of a function is not differentiable at zero, that is: $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}  | \mathfrak{R} ( f) |$ doesn't necessarily exist.

Comment: You can try to use the fact that both the real and imaginary parts of an holomorphic function are harmonic and therefore only attain their extrema if they are constant.

Comment: Yeah that sounds reasonable.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of a *subharmonic* functions? All three of yours are subharmonic, since they are compositions of something convex with something harmonic. And nonconstant subharmonic functions do not attain local maxima.